# How to schedule a cronjob which executes a kubectl command?

Tags: kubernetes, busybox, kubernetes-cronjob

How to schedule a cronjob which executes a kubectl command?

I would like to run the following kubectl command every 5 minutes:

```
kubectl patch deployment runners -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"jp-runner","env":[{"name":"START_TIME","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}' -n jp-test
```

For this, I have created a cronjob as below:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl patch deployment runners -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"jp-runner","env":[{"name":"START_TIME","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}' -n jp-test
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

But it is failing to start the container, showing the message :

```
Back-off restarting failed container
```

And with the error code 127:

```
State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    127
```

From what I checked, the error code 127 says that the command doesn't exist. How could I run the kubectl command then as a cron job ? Am I missing something?

*Note: I had posted a similar question ( [Scheduled restart of Kubernetes pod without downtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763195/scheduled-restart-of-kubernetes-pod-without-downtime) ) , but that was more of having the main deployment itself as a cronjob, here I'm trying to run a kubectl command (which does the restart) using a CronJob - so I thought it would be better to post separately*

kubectl describe cronjob hello -n jp-test:

```
Name:                       hello
Namespace:                  jp-test
Labels:                     <none>
Annotations:                kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"batch/v1beta1","kind":"CronJob","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"hello","namespace":"jp-test"},"spec":{"jobTemplate":{"spec":{"templ...
Schedule:                   */5 * * * *
Concurrency Policy:         Allow
Suspend:                    False
Starting Deadline Seconds:  <unset>
Selector:                   <unset>
Parallelism:                <unset>
Completions:                <unset>
Pod Template:
  Labels:  <none>
  Containers:
   hello:
    Image:      busybox
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Args:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      kubectl patch deployment runners -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"jp-runner","env":[{"name":"START_TIME","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}' -n jp-test
    Environment:     <none>
    Mounts:          <none>
  Volumes:           <none>
Last Schedule Time:  Wed, 27 Feb 2019 14:10:00 +0100
Active Jobs:         hello-1551273000
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From                Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----                -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  6m    cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1551272700
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  1m    cronjob-controller  Created job hello-1551273000
  Normal  SawCompletedJob   16s   cronjob-controller  Saw completed job: hello-1551272700
```

kubectl describe job hello -v=5 -n jp-test

```
Name:           hello-1551276000
Namespace:      jp-test
Selector:       controller-uid=fa009d78-3a97-11e9-ae31-ac1f6b1a0950
Labels:         controller-uid=fa009d78-3a97-11e9-ae31-ac1f6b1a0950
                job-name=hello-1551276000
Annotations:    <none>
Controlled By:  CronJob/hello
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Wed, 27 Feb 2019 15:00:02 +0100
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  controller-uid=fa009d78-3a97-11e9-ae31-ac1f6b1a0950
           job-name=hello-1551276000
  Containers:
   hello:
    Image:      busybox
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Args:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      kubectl patch deployment runners -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"jp-runner","env":[{"name":"START_TIME","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}' -n jp-test
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age              From            Message
  ----     ------                ----             ----            -------
  Normal   SuccessfulCreate      7m               job-controller  Created pod: hello-1551276000-lz4dp
  Normal   SuccessfulDelete      1m               job-controller  Deleted pod: hello-1551276000-lz4dp
  Warning  BackoffLimitExceeded  1m (x2 over 1m)  job-controller  Job has reached the specified backoff limit

Name:           hello-1551276300
Namespace:      jp-test
Selector:       controller-uid=ad52e87a-3a98-11e9-ae31-ac1f6b1a0950
Labels:         controller-uid=ad52e87a-3a98-11e9-ae31-ac1f6b1a0950
                job-name=hello-1551276300
Annotations:    <none>
Controlled By:  CronJob/hello
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Wed, 27 Feb 2019 15:05:02 +0100
Pods Statuses:  1 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  controller-uid=ad52e87a-3a98-11e9-ae31-ac1f6b1a0950
           job-name=hello-1551276300
  Containers:
   hello:
    Image:      busybox
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Args:
      /bin/sh
      -c
      kubectl patch deployment runners -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"jp-runner","env":[{"name":"START_TIME","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}' -n jp-test
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  2m    job-controller  Created pod: hello-1551276300-8d5df
```

Comment: Hi, kubectl needs to authenticate with apiserver using service account inside the pod. It could be the error

Comment: Can you provide `kubectl describe job <cron_job_name> -v=5`?

Comment: @Crou Updated my question with the details

Comment: @Chillax I've asked for a `job` not `cronjob`, I would like to see details of the job that is being spawned by cronjob, if You may.

Comment: @Chillax, yes but I think job needs to be active. Maybe remove the cronjob and apply it again and wait for job to be active.

Comment: @Crou Figured it now, pasted the contents! thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kubernetes - How to run kubectl commands inside a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642170/kubernetes-how-to-run-kubectl-commands-inside-a-container)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Long story short [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) doesn' have `kubectl` installed.

You can check it yourself using `kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox -- sh` which will run a BusyBox pod as interactive shell.

I would recommend using [bitnami/kubectl:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kubectl/).

Also keep in mind that You will need to set proper [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/), as you will get `Error from server (Forbidden): services is forbidden`

You could use something like this:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: jp-test
  name: jp-runner
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - 'patch'

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: jp-runner
  namespace: jp-test
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-jp-runner
  namespace: jp-test
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: jp-runner
  apiGroup: ""

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-jp-runner
  namespace: jp-test

---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-jp-runner
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - kubectl patch deployment runners -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"jp-runner","env":[{"name":"START_TIME","value":"'$(date +%s)'"}]}]}}}}' -n jp-test
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to make the CronJob's container to download the cluster configuration so then you can run `kubectl` commands against it. Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: drupal-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: drupal-cron
              image: juampynr/digital-ocean-cronjob:latest
              env:
                - name: DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN
                  valueFrom:
                    secretKeyRef:
                      name: api
                      key: key
              command: ["/bin/bash","-c"]
              args:
                - doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save drupster;
                  POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods -l tier=frontend -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}');
                  kubectl exec $POD_NAME -c drupal -- vendor/bin/drush core:cron;
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I posted an answer describing how I did this in a different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321138/1120652