# Setup RBAC in Kubernetes for a Cronjob running kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

```
➜  ~ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.3", GitCommit:"2d3c76f9091b6bec110a5e63777c332469e0cba2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:13:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.10", GitCommit:"e3c134023df5dea457638b614ee17ef234dc34a6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-07-08T03:40:54Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I'm trying to run kubectl from a Cronjob to change the number of pods in a deployment.

I've created the Cronjob and its role like this, following the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908449/3477266

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: scheduled-autoscaler-service-account
  namespace: default

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: scheduler-autoscaler-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - patch
  - get
  - list

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: schedule-autoscaler-role-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: scheduled-autoscaler-service-account
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: schedule-autoscaler-role
  apiGroup: ""

---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: adwords-api-scale-up-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: scheduled-autoscaler-service-account
          containers:
          - name: adwords-api-scale-up-container
            image: bitnami/kubectl:1.15-debian-9
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - "-xc"
              - |
                kubectl scale --replicas=2 --v=7 
deployment/adwords-api-deployment
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

However I am getting the following error in the pods running this job:

> Error from server (Forbidden): deployments.extensions "adwords-api-deployment" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:scheduled-autoscaler-service-account" cannot get resource "deployments" in API group "extensions" in the namespace "default"

How could I debug what the problem is? It seems for me I have given all the permissions it complains about in the message, but it's still not working.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
I solved my problem. It was just a typo in the Role name when defining it in the RoleBinding. The name there is wrong.

But I was only able to spot this after learning that I could check permissions with this command:

```
kubectl auth can-i list deployment --as=system:serviceaccount:default:scheduled-autoscaler-service-account -n default
```

I thought it was something more complicated, maybe by a lack of experience with Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can leave `apiGroup` blank in the binding. Try `apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io`?

Comment: Thank for the answer. I tried the suggestion but still getting the same error :/

Comment: Try adding the resource `deployments/scale` or similar, I forget what the subrsource is named.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to supply `kubectl` binary inside the corresponded [*Job*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/#creating-a-cron-job) template with a particular [*kubeconfig*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) file from the source k8s cluster host machine, in order to establish connection to the target k8s cluster from within the relevant Pod, determining the sufficient information about the cluster, [Authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) and [Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/) mechanisms.

I've been applying some adjustments to the origin `CronJob` config, managing to add [*hostPath*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume mount, mapping source k8s host machine `kubeconfig` path: `$HOME/.kube` under each Pod, released by a job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: adwords-api-scale-up-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: scheduled-autoscaler-service-account
          containers:
          - name: adwords-api-scale-up-container
            image: bitnami/kubectl:1.15-debian-9
            command:
              - bash
            args:
              - "-xc"
              - |
                kubectl scale --replicas=2 --v=7 deployment/adwords-api-deployment
            volumeMounts:
            - name: kubectl-config
              mountPath: /.kube/
              readOnly: true
          volumes:
          - name: kubectl-config
            hostPath:
              path: $HOME/.kube # Replace $HOME with an evident path location
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I've checked [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) rules that you've granted and they are fine, meanwhile reproducing your issue in the similar scenario on my environment.

Comment: @luislhl Does this answer your question ?
Do you still have this problem ?